# Change pages based on city

Tags: plugins

I have a wordpress site with about 5 pages. I wanted to know if there is a way to be able to change certain parts of the page based on city. Meaning like lets say someone goes to the url:

```
www.domain.com/residential/chicago
www.domain.com/residential/oklahoma
```

It can change certain parts of the site where ever i have token set to change.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what exact WordPress issue you are having, what you have tried and what were the results? Are you trying to change parts of the site only on that particular 'city page', or do you want to save the city somewhere and then change the rest of your website based on which 'city page' the user has previously visited? If it's the latter then doing this with pages is probably not the best way.

Comment: Ok i am trying to change the content of the city based on the the url, i figured i couldn't do this www.domain.com/residential/chicago but i could do this www.domain.com/residential?city=chicago which is fine for me. And i modified the page template and i added this variable $city = $_GET["city"]; but now where i run into an issue is changing the [city] token on the content of the page. I don't know where i would do that at

Comment: i guess the main question would be, is it possible to change text within a texbox made by visual composer and replace within that text everywher that shows [city] with the $_GET["city"] value?